# Read the lines of several txt files that are inside a folder and create a single text file containing all lines of text

Tags: javascript, node.js

Read the lines of several txt files that are inside a folder and create a single text file containing all lines of text. Here is an example that I make work but read only a specific file, and then i create one with the lines of text contained in that file.

```js
const testFolder = './txt_files/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
 files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
})

fs.readFile('txt_files/url-list1.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);

    fs.writeFile('txt_files/test.txt', data, function(err) {
     if(err) {
         return console.log(err);
     }
     console.log("El archivo con todas las url se guardó!");
 }); 
});
```

This example works. It reads a single file from the 'txt_files' folder, and creates a new txt with the lines of text it extracted. What I want to do is read all the files in that folder, and create a new one with all lines of text.
Please help me!

Comment: What have you tried so far to read all the files in a directory? Have you been reading through the node documentation for 'fs'? It might be worth having a closer look at the fs.readdir function - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

```
const testFolder = './txt_files/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
            fs.readFile(testFolder+file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {  
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
                fs.appendFile('txt_files/test.txt', data+"\n", function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("El archivo con todas las url se guardó!");
}); 

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What purpose does the `var str="";` serve?

Comment: Actually I forgot to erase this line, previously I was thinking to concatenate the content of file then write at once. Thank so much for reminding.

Comment: sure, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

So, using what you already provided, this is what I came up with. FS has a function called `appendFile` which creates the file if it does not exist and then appends the data to the file's EOF.
Read more on the function [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback)

I added a check for TXT-extension so this only appends data from actual text files.

```js
const testFolder = './txt_files/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        // only match TXT Files
        if (file.substring(file.length - 4, file.length) == ".txt"){
            fs.readfile(testFolder+file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                fs.appendFile(testFolder+'allfiles.txt', data+"\n", function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        }
  });
});
```